# Use pandas with Spark

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, importerror

I have a Noob Question on spark and pandas. I would like to use pandas, numpy etc.. with spark but when i import a lib i have an error. can you help me plz?
This is my code

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
import pandas

# Config
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Script")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
log4j = sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j
log4j.LogManager.getRootLogger().setLevel(log4j.Level.ERROR)
sqlCtx = SQLContext(sc)

# Importation of csv out of HDFS
data_name = "file_on_hdfs.csv"
data_textfile = sc.textFile(data_name)
```

This is the error:

```
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

How can i use pandas? It's not a local mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spark has it's own [Dataframe](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#datasets-and-dataframes) object that can be created from RDDs.

You can still use libraries such as numpy but you must install them first.

Comment: It's possible to import or install or push the package with the spark-submit?

Comment: The package should be available to `pyspark` server-side. `spark-submit` sends just your script, not its dependencies, libraries etc.

Comment: It supported by Koalas or Pandas API on Apache Spark™ 3.2. https://databricks.com/blog/2021/10/04/pandas-api-on-upcoming-apache-spark-3-2.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use Apache Arrow for this problem.

[Apache Arrow](http://arrow.apache.org/blog/2017/07/26/spark-arrow/)

It's initial version but will be more powerful in future(will see).

For installation:
[click](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/site/install.md)

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you have pandas installed in your box with `pip list|grep 'pandas'` command in a terminal.If you have a match then do a `apt-get update`. 
If you are using multi node cluster , yes you need to install pandas in all the client box.

Better to try spark version of DataFrame, but if you still like to use pandas the above method would work